# need to make an image larger when pressed. how do i do so?

Tags: ios

I'm having a set of images appear and you're able to scroll through them... the problem i'm having is making the image larger when pressed.  Any help on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Scale the target image.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CAAffineTransform to upscale any type of UIView in UIKit. This is the 'transform' property of UIView. Do something like this:

```
UIImageView *imageView = ...;    
imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.1, 1.1);
```

Please note: the 'frame' property of the UIView will not work properly when a transform is applied. Use the 'bounds' and 'center' property instead.

You can animate the 'transform' property just like the 'frame' property:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.1, 1.1);
}];
```

Alternatively you can just change the frame to the new size and back, but it is more work.

Comment: To hook the "press / release" events, you can either use classic target-action methods (`TouchDownInside`, `TouchUpInside`), a gesture recognizer, or subclass the low-level `touchesBegan`/`touchesEnded` methods. If it's not a single component and you need reusable code, I'd go for the latter.